# Tomcat service is going down

Tags: jenkins

Tomcat service is going down .. We are running test plans on Jenkins, at times tomcat service is going down, there are no errors seen in logs. This occurs very rarely, but what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of low memory assigned to jvm, by increasing memory we were able to run jobs peacefully without dropping of services